# Did Ram become Chakravarti Samrat?

Tags: ramayana, rama

Did Ram conquered whole of Aryavrata ? Did he become Chakravarti Samrat ?

Did the rule over all over Aryavrata or only Kosala Janpad ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rama conducted 10 Ashwamedha Yagas. This means all the kings of India were subjucated and under his rule. So Lord Rama was  chakravartin.

> Reigning for ten thousand years, **he offered up ten horse sacrifices,**
> distributing immense wealth in charity, and Rama, whose arms reached
> to his knees, the powerful elder brother of Lakshmana, **ruled the earth**
> in glory and performed many sacrifices with his sons, brothers and
> kinsfolk.

Chapter 128, Yuddha kanda, Valmiki Ramayana.

> Having dwelt, in the observance of severe penances, for four and ten
> years in the woods, **Rama performed ten Horse-sacrifices of great
> splendour and to them the freest access was given to all.** Possessed
> of youth, of a dark complexion, with red eyes, he looked like the
> leader of an elephantine herd. With aims stretching down to his knees
> and of handsome face, his shoulders were like those of a lion and the
> might of his arms great. **Ascending upon the throne of Ayodhya, he
> ruled for ten thousand and ten hundred years.”**

Section XXIX, Rajadharmanusasana Parva, Mahabharata.